# The string is missing the terminator: "

Tags: sharepoint

I try to install SharePoint 2016 offline but first I tried run the following script "PreinstallRoles" as below:
Import-Module ServerManager 
Add-WindowsFeature Net-Framework-Features,Web-Server,Web-WebServer,Web-Common-Http,Web-Static-Content,Web-Default-Doc,Web-Dir-Browsing,Web-Http-Errors,Web-App-Dev,Web-Asp-Net,Web-Net-Ext,Web-ISAPI-Ext,Web-ISAPI-Filter,Web-Health,Web-Http-Logging,Web-Log-Libraries,Web-Request-Monitor,Web-Http-Tracing,Web-Security,Web-Basic-Auth,Web-Windows-Auth,Web-Filtering,Web-Digest-Auth,Web-Performance,Web-Stat-Compression,Web-Dyn-Compression,Web-Mgmt-Tools,Web-Mgmt-Console,Web-Mgmt-Compat,Web-Metabase,Application-Server,AS-Web-Support,AS-TCP-Port-Sharing,AS-WAS-Support, AS-HTTP-Activation,AS-TCP-Activation,AS-Named-Pipes,AS-Net-Framework,WAS,WAS-Process-Model,WAS-NET-Environment,WAS-Config-APIs,Web-Lgcy-Scripting,Windows-Identity-Foundation,Server-Media-Foundation,Xps-Viewer –Source C:\sources\sxs

But I get the Powershell error message:
The string is missing the terminator. This is the exact message:

> ```
> At C:\SharePoint 2016 Installation\Scripts\sp2016_preinstallRoles.ps1:2 char:776  
> + ... n,Xps-Viewer â€“Source C:\sources\sxs  
> +                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  
> The string is missing the terminator: ".  
>     + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException  
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString
> ```

Any idea or tip is very appreciated

Regards
Ashraf

Comment: It seems that you have a typo in "–Source C:\sources\sxs". Maybe because you  copy/paste and you have dash. Try with hyphen char "-Source C:\sources\sxs"

Comment: That's right. I typed the script manually from scratch without changing anything and it works. This is comfirm what you wrote that there was an issue when doing copy/paste. Thanks a lot for your input.

Answer (score 1):

Added as answer.

It seems that you have a typo in "–Source C:\sources\sxs". Maybe because you  copy/paste and you have dash. Try with hyphen char "-Source C:\sources\sxs"